# Unity Xcode LowLevelCullingLoops.cpp Crash

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've been experiencing a crash when loading the first mission past my menu screen. As soon as my first mission loads, Xcode crashes with this error:

```
LowLevelCullingLoops.cpp: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Anyone have any idea what this means? I've been trying to debug it for a few days now. Here's some things that Ive done:

- Removed all occlusion culling data
- Disabled occlusion culling on the camera
- Copied all assets into a new scene
- Removed 50% of assets from the scene
- Cleaning Xcode project
- Testing multiple devices
- Switched from LWRP to URP
- Updated to the newest version of unity (2019.3.2f1)

None of this has resolved my issue. I'm getting crashes on an iPhone 7+ and iPad Pro (2017), both of which are running the latest version of iOS. The crash does not happen when I build for macOS.

Any insights would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What is your camera position?

Comment: My cameras position is X: 0, Y: 0.8, Z: 0 with a rotation of  0, 0, 0 and a scale of 1, 1, 1. I used to have an animation on the camera that played in the beginning to add a cinematic effect for the levels intro. Its been since removed as I've been debugging this issue. Its interesting you bring that up as the crash seems to have been happening since I added that animation . Could it be correlated?

Comment: This crash usually happens whenever camera position is `NaN`. Check if your animation changes your camera position to `NaN`.

Comment: I see. Would it still affect the game if I no long called the animation in the scene? I removed the cameras animation along with its animation controller and it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: Hey @0xBFE1A8 I was actually able to debug the issue. I just deleted my old camera and created a new one. I guess the old one got corrupt somehow? Thanks again, if it wasn't for your insight I probably would not have figured it out. If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash usually happens whenever camera position is `NaN`. Try to reset your component or replace it with a new one.